# How to return to my Menu C++

Tags: c++, loops, menu, return, converters

Here's my program , iam so sorry because iam just a noobie so i would like to ask how can i return to the menu because iam using a switch statement and i want to ask the user after he/she finish to convert . see the comment in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int option;
float C,F,result;
char rpt;

cout<<"Temperature Converter"
    <<"\n1.Celsius to Fahrenheit"
    <<"\n2.Fahrenheit to Celsius"
    <<"\n3.Exit"
    <<"\n\nEnter a number from 1 to 3: ";
cin>>option;

switch (option)
{
    case 1:
    system ("CLS"); 
    cout<<"Celsius to Fahrenheit!"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEnter Celsius: ";
    cin>>C;

    result=C*9/5+32; 

    cout<<C<<" Celsius is equivalent to "<<result<<" Fahrenheit."<<endl<<endl;


    cout<<"Would you like to convert again? Type Y to try again OR N to exit. : ";
    cin>>rpt;

    if (rpt='Y')

    //What Code should i put here?


    break;
```

Comment: The program is not even syntactically valid...

Answer (score 1):

The code asking whether the user wants to repeat belongs *after* the switch block. Also you should be using the == operator for comparison. So something like

```
do {

    // Get menu choice
    ...

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            ...
             break;

        case 2:
            ...
            break;

        ...
    }

    cout<<"Would you like to convert again? Type Y to try again OR N to exit. : ";
    cin>>rpt;
} while (rpt == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a loop. something like this:

```
bool ended = false;
while (!ended)
{
    //some code
}
```

If the answer is N change ended to true.

Or, as some people prefer:

```
bool ended;
do
{
    //some code
} while(!ended);
```

Comment: Since we would presume that he would never abort prior to the first pass through the loop, my preference is `do { ... /* maybe set ended = true; */ ... } while(!ended);`

Answer (score 0):

put the code into a do while loop

```
int main()
{
   do {
   .....
   } while(rpt);// instead of if 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make a function, that shows the menu and returns the selected option
Example :

```
      int showMenu() {
      //Show menu
      //Read option
     //Return option
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// put the label Start below the declaration //

if (rpt == 'Y')

system ("CLS");
goto Start;

else

exit (0);
```

Comment: Instead of just giving the code, please explain the logic. This enables both the OP and other readers to learn the principles behind the solution, and apply it to their specific problem.

Comment: Please try to add some explanation for code. It will be helpful